Parámetros en un template de overleaf para ajustar tipo de fuente y posición de título, etc
Hace un tiempo que no pasaba por aquí pero creo que en este momento lo necesito. Intentaré ser sintético e ir retocando algún aspecto más.
En un template para Overleaf intento ajustar tipo/tamaño de fuente de los diferentes apartados título, subtítulo, autor, etc, además de la posición de cada uno de ellos en las diferentes páginas (portada, cuerpo y contraportada). He intentado añadir opciones en el .tex pero no cambia nada.
Pongo el enlace del template aquí y si podéis ayudarme lo agradecería.
https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lix-novel-template/shnjdvjrpjtd
Un saludo para todos.
